# Stop icons repeating

Tags: java, jframe

I am making a JTable that overrides to put icons into the needed tables. This is what I have done. But the result prints icons in ALL cells not just my first cell and is not what I want. Here is what is resulted:

[image]

```
import com.skype.User;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import java.awt.*;

class BoardTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {


    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                                   boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {

        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
                isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
        JLabel label = (JLabel)super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,isSelected, hasFocus,row, col);
        //row is the username
        if(col == 0) {
            try {
                User temp = Functions.returnUser(value.toString());
                ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/" + temp.getStatus().toString() + ".png"));
                label.setIcon(imageIcon);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
            return label;
        }else{
            return c;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `label.setIcon(null);` to your `else` block, otherwise you're just returning whatever it was last set to

See [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for more details